# Add fixed item and non-removable item to select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, ecmascript-6, jquery-select2

I have a mail module and I want to add the mentioned ([in the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFnsk.png)) email or hr@example.com to be **fixed selected and non-removable** option in cc in a multi selection select2. How may I achieve this? any idea?

Here is my Blade syntax for selecting cc :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>CC <span class="astirered">*</span></label>
    {!! Form::select('cc[]', $employee_list, $mail_cc_user_id, ['class'=>'form-control select2','multiple']) !!}
    <span class="astirered">{!! $errors->first('cc') !!}</span>
</div>
```

and this is the script of select 2 :

```
$('.select2').select2({
    placeholder: "Please select one"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think select 2 has a built in way for that, but with some additional JQuery it is possible to hide it. If you look the select box with inspector you will find something like this

```
<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="mni@email.com" data-select2-id="id">
    <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>
    mni@email.com
</li>
```

You could remove that x by jQuery like this:

```
$('li.select2-selection__choice[title="mni@email.com"]').find('span.select2-selection__choice__remove').remove();
```

And then for exmaple you could mark that specific email default selected in the form, then run that jQuery command when document loads.